# How to make highlighted text remain highlighted when selecting another button?

Tags: java, selenium

My application's mechanic is to highlight a piece of text and then press a button to make that highlighted text an answer. My issue is that when I select the button, the highlighted text disappears.

The text I want to highlight is within this HTML format:

```
<div id="passage_432" class="passage ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="display: block;" aria-labelledby="passage_432_header" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false"> 
    <p>This is a test passage to test 323</p>
</div>
```

[Application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOtvd.png)

The code I am using to select the text is as follows:

```
WebElement makeSelection = driver.findElement(By.xpath(array3[9]));

Actions action = new Actions (driver);
action.moveToElement(startLocation, 0, 0);
action.clickAndHold(startLocation);
action.moveToElement(startLocation, 3, 0);
action.release();
action.perform();

makeSelection.click();
```

Edit(3/3/2016)

I found a weird solution. The code only works when I mouse-click out of the browser window I am running my automated test in.  I think what happens is when clicking within the browser, the system thinks I am highlighting something else and thus it disappears.  The issue now is that I need to find a way to deselect the browser and still have my test run.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your first <div> tag is closed without including id, class, etc. Wasn't sure if that's how it was in your code base or if it was an accident while copying over to SO.

Comment: Ah sorry.  It was an accident when copying over to SO. Thanks for the suggested edit.

Comment: Have you tried interacting with the `makeSelection` element as part of the action chain as well? I'm not sure if it will help but it's the only thing I can think of at the moment.

Comment: I did try that and it ended up in the same kind of error.  Thanks though!  I edited my post with my latest find.  Its an odd one though there might be a solution